# Coldfusion Builder Project Path

Tags: configuration, coldfusion, path, builder

I just started using CF Builder with the included CF server 11  I want to use it to continue a project I had started on CF 10 and Dreamweaver.

CF builder insists on creating projects as subdirectories of the server root
wwwroot/project.

The project I am trying to import has a lot of includes and links that refer to the home directory:
Example: `<cfinclude template="/includes/header.cfm">`

That causes fails as the correct path should now be: 
`<cfinclude template="/project/includes/header.cfm">`

But I can't modify all the links in the project that way as when it's deployed it needs to keep the links as they are now.

How can I configure CF builder to either recognize wwwroot/project/ as the "/" home for this particular project, or just work off wwwroot?

Comment: P.S. 
I also tried using apache and virtual hosts but then ran into problems with apache using coldfusion so I gave up on that route. 
I realize I'm probably making all sorts of newbie mistakes. But I've spend hours on this - appreciate the help.

Comment: "CF builder insists on creating projects as subdirectories"... doesn't it just create the project in whichever directory you tell it? I've not used CFB 3.0, but that's the way previous versions of CFB & indeed Eclipse in general works. Has it changed in 3?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but it creates a subdirectory under the webroot with the project name - so I end up with paths like "wwwroot/project/index.cfm" instead of the prefered "wwwroot/index.cfm"
So I've tried to create the project one level above the root and calling the project wwwroot but it didn't accept that

Comment: Are relative paths an option?

Comment: Hi - the problem with relative paths is that I call files from different subdirectories.For example the header , which has the navigation menu, is an include to /includes/header.cfm  but the menu itself has HTML links which are also relative because they can be called in from anywhere. ex: to go to the site home "/index.cfm" as an absolute works but not as a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The best way to do this is to set up virtual hosts - each a directory. That way it should match the structure that CFB expects.
where there is a wwwroot - but each project is a subdirectory which can be it's own "home".